# A map on the $2n$-sphere and degree zero

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f : \mathbb{S}^{2n} \to \mathbb{S}^{2n}$ is continue e $f(x) \neq -f(-x)  \quad\forall x$. Prove that $f$ has degree zero.

Thanks!!

Comment: Where are the spheres sitting? You must have some additive structure for $-x$ and $-\operatorname{f}(x)$ to have any meaning.

Comment: I'm trying to apply the following result: "If $f:\mathbb{S}^{2n} \to \mathbb{S}^{2n}$ is continue else exist $x$ such that $f(x)=x$ or exist $y$ such that $f(y)=-y$".

Comment: @MarceloMoreira What does $-y$ mean? Writing $-y$ implies that you have some rule that allows you to add points on the sphere, that there is a $0$ for which $y + (-y) = 0$. How are you defining addition in your sphere? Is it embedded in a vector space? Perhaps $\mathbb{S}^{2n} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}?$

Comment: Aw come on, @FlybyNight: It is standard notation that $S^n$ refers to the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: @FlybyNight $\mathbb{S}^n$ admits a standard $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action, usually written $x\mapsto -x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x) \ne -f(-x)$ for all $x$, the function $\varphi(x, t) = ((1-t)f(x) + (t)f(-x))/|(1-t)f(x) + (t)f(-x)|$ is well-defined.  In fact $\varphi$ defines a homotopy from $f$ to $g$, where $g$ is the map $g(x) = f(-x)$.  Since $g$ is just the composition of the antipodal map $-\mathbf{1}$ followed by $f$, the degree of $g$ is $\deg(g) = (-1)^{2n+1} \deg(f) = -\deg(f)$.  But if $f$ is homotopic to $g$, then ...

Comment: Let the OP do the work...

Comment: @ChrisGerig, are you complaining that I answered his question?  I don't understand.

Comment: If $f$ is homotopic to $g$, then $deg(g)=deg(f)$. On the other hand, $deg(g)=-deg(f)$. It follows $deg(f)=-deg(f)$, then $deg(f)=0$.

Comment: Yes, @Adeel: The point is not for those of us who know how to solve problems to write out complete solutions for those who don't. Give a hint or ask a good leading question.

Comment: @TedShifrin, could you tell me where this rule is written?  Or is it you who decided what the "point" of this website is?  Personally I agree with your principle for homework problems, but the OP never mentioned this being one.

Comment: It isn't a rule. I was supporting @ChrisGerig and addressing your "I don't understand." Most of us learn more by working on a problem than by reading complete solutions. Of course, I speak with the perspective of a teacher here. I tend to suspect more posting are homework, particularly when the OP doesn't give any idea of how he/she has approached the problem.